# How can I send a multipart form-data PUT request with apache

Tags: java, apache, multipartform-data, put

I hardly try to send a PUT request whit `HttpsURLConnection` but I cant make it and I don’t even get a response code, so now I want to do that whit Apache.

Here the question.

How can I send this request

```
curl -s -uedoweb-admin:admin -F"data=@/home/raul/test/t1/6376990.pdf;type=application/pdf" -XPUT api.localhost/resource/frl:6376979/data
```

and here the trace:  http://pastebin.com/jJmungAy

in Java with the Apache lib.

Comment: What did you try with HTTPSURLConnection? Maybe that one can get fixed. The other question is too broad e.g. the idea is not to code it for you.

Comment: here the HTTPSURLConnection problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34136432/upload-multiform-data . Dont need to code for me just give a good start