# Android send HTTP PUT, but error: isDataScedulerEnabled():False

Tags: android, http

I'm trying to send a PUT request but failing bad in it.
Only the first time I'm trying to send data the following line follows up in the log (in further use no exceptions are thrown):

> E/DataScheduler: isDataSchedulerEnabled():false

I tried to google out what could that possibly mean, but with no luck. And even that in the further attempts on sending data the mentioned exception wont raise anymore, still no data is being sent. I'm trying to send it on my own server and I can see no connections are received on that side. Using my Android's browser I can send a successful GET request however.

I've also set the permission for Internet already by:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I'm not very familiar with Java or Android but as far as I know the request should be formed and sent the following way:

```
public void sendFilesWithPut(String address, String file) {
    new AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                //Log.d("HTTP:","Address:"+params[0]+":"+params[1]+" file:"+params[2]);
                URL url = new URL("http://" + params[0] + ":" + params[1]);
                HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
                httpCon.setRequestMethod("PUT");
                OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(httpCon.getOutputStream());
                out.write(params[2]);
                out.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute(address, Integer.toString(port), file);
}
```

I can print a line to Log every time I attempt to send a PUT request and it's all correct: IP, port and the to-be-sent-String.

Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that params[0] and params[1] are actually the address and port for your url. If so then you may wish to refer to the following post:

[Making PUT request with JSON data using HttpURLConnection is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678208/making-put-request-with-json-data-using-httpurlconnection-is-not-working)

Where the content will be sent if you start interaction with the response, so add the following:

```
System.err.println(httpCon.getResponseCode());
```

as per the post, and see if that works?

Comment: Ah, that little piece of code made the trick! Strange it wasn't in any the examples where I learned the code from. Anyway, thanks man. You've officially saved my day :)

Comment: Don't mention it buddy, glad to help a fellow noob... hard to get helpful or good answers on here, usually have to answer my own questions. Best of luck! :)